# How to fix an ArrayOutOfBounds exception in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm rather new to java, and I am trying to make a program to do various things to a picture given by the user (rotate, flip, invert, etc). However, I have run into an error in this piece of code when trying to invert the image's colours:

```
public static int[][] invert(int[][] result){

    int[][]inver = new int[255][255];

    for(int y = result.length-1; y>=0; y--){
        for(int x = result.length-1; x>=0; x--){
            inver[y][x]=result[y][x];
        }
    }
    return inver;   
}
```

The 2d array 'result' in the parameters is an array with numbers relating to the colours of the image's pixels, a length of 255 by 255 and integers between 0-255 filling it. The error I get is an ArrayOutOfBounds exception of 328 at the line 'inver[y][x]=result[y][x];'. From my understanding, this exception is caused when you try to access an array element that isn't there, but I don't know why it would be that big of a number or what is causing it. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly apreciated

Comment: Second one should be `result[x].length`

Comment: *I don't know why it would be that big of a number.* Likely because `result.length > 328`. Did you try debugging?